# Markers displayed one on top of the other

Tags: java, android

> The markers that are being displayed are on top of each other can cannot be seen properly.

Is there any way to re position marker so that it is not on top of other markers.

```
 day1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.day1);
    day1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LatLng c = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            for(int i=1; i<=3; i++)
            {
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(c).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));

            }

        }
    });
```

Markers are as shown in image.

[image: Map]

Answer (score 0):

you can add some space between them to give them a little extra space.

Inside your for, and before of placing the maker, use this

```
double offset = i / 60d (replace this number with the distance you want to add);
lat = lat + offset;
lng = lng + offset;
```

Then you can add the marker.